# Is there a way to optimize this T-SQL query to use less spool space?

Tags: t-sql, join, optimization, union

Running out of spool space wondering if the query can be optimized.

I've tried running a DISTINCT and UNION ALL, Group By doesn't make sense.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.EMAIL, T2.BILLG_STATE_CD, T2.BILLG_ZIP_CD
    FROM
    (SELECT EMAIL
        FROM    CAT
            UNION ALL

    SELECT  EMAIL
        FROM    DOG
            UNION ALL

    SELECT  email As EMAIL
        FROM    MOUSE) As T1

 LEFT JOIN HAMSTER As T2 ON T1.EMAIL =T2.EMAIL_ADDR;
```

I will need to do this same type of data pull often, looking for a viable solution other than doing three separate joins.

I need to union multiple tables (T1) and join columns from another table (T2) on (T1).

Comment: `DISTINCT` is likely your overhead here. Do you need it?

Comment: No, I tried it with out as well.

Comment: I think you can do `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.  I don't know that it will help much -- it depends on how many duplicates you might have.  Maybe an `inner join`?  I don't know if you need anything from T1 if there isn't a match in T2.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE T2.ord_creatd_dt > DATE '2019-01-01' and T2.ord_creatd_dt < DATE '2019-11-08'